# How do i make my now executable shell script accept a string

Tags: c++, shell

i have a shell script findName.sh that will locate a name that matches a user id that I enter.

```
#!/bin/sh 
# for use , in some  project.....

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
# if there is exactly one command line arg used with the command
# do something(s).
    if [ -s /class/rolls/CSCE215-803 ]; then
    grep $1 /class/rolls/CSCE215-803 > ./output

if [ -s ./output ]; then
    cut -c 1-30 ./output
else
    echo "Sorry that person is not in CSCE215-803"
fi
else
    echo "CSCE215-803 file does not exist!"
    fi
else

 echo "Incorrect number of arguments"
 exit 1
fi
```

This works fine...

but when i put it into a c++ file main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    system("./findName.sh");

    return 0;
}
```

when it is compiled to findName and i try to execute it i.e. (./findName someUserId), it will always return "incorrect number of arguments". I know this is probably a simple fix, but I'm new to this.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You need to put the arguments to your C++ program into the string you are passing to `system` to do what you want but again why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprised? Your shell script and your C program are two completely different things. With the following line

```
system("./findName.sh");
```

you only call your script, but you don't pass any arguments. You should call your script like this

```
system("./findName.sh hereisyourargument");
```

Comment: so what if i wanted the "herisyourargument" to be whatever i want to type into the keyboard?

Comment: in this case you need to set up your command line string dynamically. But don't forget to escape your argument. The better option is using `execve` or similar instead of `system`, but they are only easy to use if you don't need to fork your program